# ElasticSearch 0.90.2 StreamCorruptedException on asking port 9300

Tags: exception, configuration, elasticsearch

I've just unpacked elasticsearch-0.90.2.zip on Windows XP, and started bin/elasticsearch.bat.

I've set JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jre7, as it was a problem at first run.

I'm trying to connect it from Google Chrome 27.0.1453.116.

According to elasticsearch.yml, "ElasticSearch, by default, binds itself to the 0.0.0.0 address", but 0.0.0.0:9200 responds 108 (net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID).

localhost:9200 or 127.0.0.1:9200 responds correctly: { "ok" : true, etc.

localhost:9300 responds 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE), and displays StreamCorruptedException in the console window:

```
[2013-07-25 10:42:30,419][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Happy Birthday] exc
eption caught on transport layer [[id: 0x478ae9b7, /127.0.0.1:1627 => /127.0.0.1
:9300]], closing connection
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.decode(SizeH
eaderFrameDecoder.java:27)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callD
ecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messa
geReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.h
andleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUps
tream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$Default
ChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(Ope
nChannelsHandler.java:74)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUps
tream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUps
tream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(C
hannels.java:268)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(C
hannels.java:255)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioW
orker.java:88)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.p
rocess(AbstractNioWorker.java:109)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector
.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.r
un(AbstractNioWorker.java:90)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWo
rker.java:178)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(Thread
RenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.ru
n(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[2013-07-25 10:42:30,435][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Happy Birthday] exc
eption caught on transport layer [[id: 0x478ae9b7, /127.0.0.1:1627 :> /127.0.0.1
:9300]], closing connection
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.decode(SizeH
eaderFrameDecoder.java:27)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callD
ecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.clean
up(FrameDecoder.java:482)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.chann
elDisconnected(FrameDecoder.java:365)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.h
andleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUps
tream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$Default
ChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(Ope
nChannelsHandler.java:74)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUps
tream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUps
tream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnect
ed(Channels.java:396)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.c
lose(AbstractNioWorker.java:361)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipe
lineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:81)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipe
lineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDow
nstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:574)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.close(Channels.java:8
12)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(Abstract
Channel.java:197)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.exceptionCaught(Nett
yTransport.java:505)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.exceptionCaug
ht(MessageChannelHandler.java:224)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.h
andleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUps
tream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$Default
ChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.excep
tionCaught(FrameDecoder.java:377)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.h
andleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUps
tream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$Default
ChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(Ope
nChannelsHandler.java:74)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUps
tream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUps
tream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(C
hannels.java:525)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.AbstractChannelSink.exceptionC
aught(AbstractChannelSink.java:48)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.notifyH
andlerException(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:658)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUps
tream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:566)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$Default
ChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(Ope
nChannelsHandler.java:74)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUps
tream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUps
tream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(C
hannels.java:268)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(C
hannels.java:255)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioW
orker.java:88)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.p
rocess(AbstractNioWorker.java:109)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector
.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.r
un(AbstractNioWorker.java:90)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWo
rker.java:178)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(Thread
RenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.ru
n(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've read about similar situations, but now there is no other node running, no networking, nothing uses the port, it is my first standalone ElasticSearch engine on the local machine with default configuration.

I can't imagine what should there be on port 1627 - perhaps it is the clue.
What do I wrong - or any solution?

Comment: if connecting via port 9200 responds, then what's the issue?

Comment: Perhaps nothing, but I thought something is corrupted.

Comment: Did my answer clarify things for you?

Answer (score 13):

Nothing is corrupted. The 9300 port is used for inter-node communication and uses an internal binary protocol, thus you can't use it from the browser. In order to use the 9300 port you have to use the [Java API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/java-api/), either Node client or Transport client, which both understand the internal binary protocol.

From the browser you should only use the 9200 port, which is the one that exposes the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem. As I discovered issue is inside configs(`/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` by default). There is a tricky parameter `http.enabled` which was set to `false` by default. For fix you just need to set it to `true`:

`http.port: 9200
   http.enabled: true`

I hope it will help.