# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on **elasticsearch 0.90.5** on **ubuntu 13.04** in LAN environment. When I start it I get `StreamCorruptedException`. There are no other instances running and I haven't configured anything else. [Things were good](http://prayag-waves.blogspot.com/2013/10/first-night-hack-on-elasticsearch.html) when I did the same thing on my laptop with ubuntu-12.04.

#### Full stacktrace is as below :

```
prayag@prayag:~$ JVM/elasticsearch-0.90.5/bin/elasticsearch -f
[2013-10-22 02:01:40,400][INFO ][node                     ] [The Blank] version[0.90.5], pid[10767], build[c8714e8/2013-09-17T12:50:20Z]
[2013-10-22 02:01:40,400][INFO ][node                     ] [The Blank] initializing ...
[2013-10-22 02:01:40,414][INFO ][plugins                  ] [The Blank] loaded [], sites []
[2013-10-22 02:01:43,631][INFO ][node                     ] [The Blank] initialized
[2013-10-22 02:01:43,632][INFO ][node                     ] [The Blank] starting ...
[2013-10-22 02:01:43,744][INFO ][transport                ] [The Blank] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.3.87:9300]}
[2013-10-22 02:01:43,814][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [The Blank] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x377d3d6b, /192.168.1.178:53828 => /192.168.3.87:9300]], closing connection
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.decode(SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.java:27)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:109)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:90)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
[2013-10-22 02:01:43,817][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [The Blank] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x377d3d6b, /192.168.1.178:53828 :> /192.168.3.87:9300]], closing connection
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.decode(SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.java:27)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.cleanup(FrameDecoder.java:482)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelDisconnected(FrameDecoder.java:365)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:396)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:361)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:81)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:574)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.close(Channels.java:812)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(AbstractChannel.java:197)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.exceptionCaught(NettyTransport.java:501)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.exceptionCaught(MessageChannelHandler.java:228)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.exceptionCaught(FrameDecoder.java:377)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:525)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.AbstractChannelSink.exceptionCaught(AbstractChannelSink.java:48)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.notifyHandlerException(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:658)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:566)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:109)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:90)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
[2013-10-22 02:01:45,285][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [The Blank] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x7da77a28, /192.168.1.178:53837 => /192.168.3.87:9300]], closing connection
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.decode(SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.java:27)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:109)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:90)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
[2013-10-22 02:01:45,287][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [The Blank] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x7da77a28, /192.168.1.178:53837 :> /192.168.3.87:9300]], closing connection
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.decode(SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.java:27)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.cleanup(FrameDecoder.java:482)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelDisconnected(FrameDecoder.java:365)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:396)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:361)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:81)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:574)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.close(Channels.java:812)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(AbstractChannel.java:197)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.exceptionCaught(NettyTransport.java:501)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.exceptionCaught(MessageChannelHandler.java:228)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.exceptionCaught(FrameDecoder.java:377)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:525)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.AbstractChannelSink.exceptionCaught(AbstractChannelSink.java:48)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.notifyHandlerException(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:658)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:566)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:109)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:90)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
[2013-10-22 02:01:46,790][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [The Blank] new_master [The Blank][rQTIOt33TiWyJC5t87_qNw][inet[/192.168.3.87:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2013-10-22 02:01:46,839][INFO ][discovery                ] [The Blank] elasticsearch/rQTIOt33TiWyJC5t87_qNw
[2013-10-22 02:01:46,895][INFO ][http                     ] [The Blank] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.3.87:9200]}
[2013-10-22 02:01:46,895][INFO ][node                     ] [The Blank] started
[2013-10-22 02:01:47,705][INFO ][gateway                  ] [The Blank] recovered [40] indices into cluster_state
```

**When I check the cluster status, I find it RED, which means the [specific shard is not allocated in the cluster.](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html)**

```
prayag@prayag:~$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 34,
  "active_shards" : 34,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 366
}
```

**I can hit `-XGET`s.**

```
prayag@prayag:~$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty=true'
{
  "ok" : true,
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "The Blank",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "0.90.5",
    "build_hash" : "c8714e8e0620b62638f660f6144831792b9dedee",
    "build_timestamp" : "2013-09-17T12:50:20Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

But, with `-XPUT`s, it battles for about a minute and then throws `UnavailableShardsException`.

```
prayag@prayag:~$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/1' -d '
> {
>     "title": "The Godfather",
>     "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
>     "year": 1972
> }'
{"error":"UnavailableShardsException[[movies][2] [2] shardIt, [0] active : Timeout waiting for [1m], request: index {[movies][movie][3], source[\n{\n    \"title\": \"The Godfather\",\n    \"director\": \"Francis Ford Coppola\",\n    \"year\": 1972\n}]}]","status":503}
```

I found similar issue at google-group, [how to resolve elasticsearch status red](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elasticsearch/k-TYhXM8dXQ/yzN81x1db4IJ), where David Pilato  suggests

> My opinion is that you created some indexes and some of them with no
>   replica. You started more than one node in your LAN. Then, you
>   shutdown one node.
>
> ES can not give you a green or yellow health as some of your documents
>   (index with no replica) can not be seen by ES.

But, I don't think thats true in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I FIXED IT** **changing the `cluster.name`** from older one `elasticsearch` -> **to new one** `prayagcluster` at **cluster section of `elasticsearch.yml`.**

```
prayag@prayag:~$ vi JVM/elasticsearch-0.90.5/config/elasticsearch.yml 

################################### Cluster ###################################

# Cluster name identifies your cluster for auto-discovery. If you're running
# multiple clusters on the same network, make sure you're using unique names.
#
cluster.name: prayagcluster
```

Comment: I have the same problem and I try a simple GET. I got the same error. Maybe is another problem: before I running an elasticsearch (without -f) and I killed (kill pid). How can I recover and have a single elasticsearch node correctly running?

Comment: @g.annunziata Are `GET` requests (like `$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty=true'` or `curl -XGET  'http://localhost:9200/YOUR_INDEX/YOUR_TYPE/_search'`) working?

Comment: Man, I found my own answer after facing the same issue after 3 years !!! Damn me :) I can not upvote my own own answer :(

Comment: My fault in docker-compose:     - cluster.name="docker-cluster" WRONG, just fix with       - cluster.name=docker-cluster

Answer (score 20):

You will see this is if you try to connect to the cluster syncing port instead of the API port.

The API location you curl from is configured in elasticsearch.yml as `http.port`, default 9200.

The port for nodes to sync with each other in a cluster is `transport.tcp.port`, default 9300.

See also [ElasticSearch 0.90.2 StreamCorruptedException on asking port 9300](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854910/elasticsearch-0-90-2-streamcorruptedexception-on-asking-port-9300)

Answer (score 0):

In `{Sonar_Install_Directory}/conf/sonar.properties` Please change the `# Elasticsearch port`. Default is `9001`. Use `0` to get a free port.

```
# As a security precaution, should be blocked by a firewall and not exposed to the Internet.
sonar.search.port=<<new port>>
```

ex: `9005`

Changing the above and set `JAVA_HOME=""`; set `PATH=""`; set `classpath=""`; and set `path="Jdk 11/bin path"`; set `classpath="Jdk 11/bin path`" and then with jdk 11 being set run `StartSonar.bat` again. Your problem will get solved