# Problem starting SonarQube on localhost:9000

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm running SonarQube for quality test. When starting, I tried to load the localhost:9000, but it doesn't work. I have Java 11 and I'm using Windows 10. When I executed `StartSonar.bat`, I got the logging shown below. I searched on the net, but couldn't find what the problem might be. I'm using SonarQube version 7.4, I also tried 7.9, but it has the same problem.

```
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2021.01.11 19:06:57 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\sonarqube-7.4\temp
jvm 1    | 2021.01.11 19:06:57 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
jvm 1    | 2021.01.11 19:06:57 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [C:\sonarqube-7.4\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.9\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -server -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\sonarqube-7.4\elasticsearch -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch -Epath.conf=C:\sonarqube-7.4\temp\conf\es
jvm 1    | 2021.01.11 19:06:57 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
jvm 1    | 2021.01.11 19:06:57 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
jvm 1    | 2021.01.11 19:06:57 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
jvm 1    | WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
jvm 1    | WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil (file:/C:/sonarqube-7.4/lib/common/netty-common-4.1.13.Final.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
jvm 1    | WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil
jvm 1    | WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
jvm 1    | WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
jvm 1    | 2021.01.11 19:06:59 WARN  app[][o.e.t.n.Netty4Transport] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x3fb5a3e3, L:/127.0.0.1:8783 - R:/127.0.0.1:9001]], closing connection
jvm 1    | io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format, got (48,54,54,50)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:459)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:241)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
jvm 1    | Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format, got (48,54,54,50)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.validateMessageHeader(TcpTransport.java:1276)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.decode(Netty4SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.java:36)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
jvm 1    |      ... 19 common frames omitted
jvm 1    | 2021.01.11 19:06:59 WARN  app[][o.e.t.n.Netty4Transport] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x3fb5a3e3, L:/127.0.0.1:8783 ! R:/127.0.0.1:9001]], closing connection
jvm 1    | io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format, got (48,54,54,50)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:459)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:392)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:359)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:342)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelInactive(LoggingHandler.java:167)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1329)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:908)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:744)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:462)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
jvm 1    | Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format, got (48,54,54,50)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.validateMessageHeader(TcpTransport.java:1276)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.decode(Netty4SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.java:36)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
jvm 1    |      ... 20 common frames omitted
jvm 1    | 2021.01.11 19:07:02 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
jvm 1    | 2021.01.11 19:07:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2021.01.11 19:07:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
jvm 1    | 2021.01.11 19:07:03 WARN  app[][o.e.t.n.Netty4Transport] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xdff2f2af, L:/127.0.0.1:8848 - R:/127.0.0.1:9001]], closing connection
jvm 1    | io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format, got (48,54,54,50)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:459)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:241)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
jvm 1    | Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format, got (48,54,54,50)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.validateMessageHeader(TcpTransport.java:1276)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.decode(Netty4SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.java:36)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
jvm 1    |      ... 19 common frames omitted
jvm 1    | 2021.01.11 19:07:03 WARN  app[][o.e.t.n.Netty4Transport] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xdff2f2af, L:/127.0.0.1:8848 ! R:/127.0.0.1:9001]], closing connection
jvm 1    | io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format, got (48,54,54,50)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:459)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:392)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:359)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:342)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelInactive(LoggingHandler.java:167)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1329)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:908)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:744)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:462)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
jvm 1    | Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format, got (48,54,54,50)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.validateMessageHeader(TcpTransport.java:1276)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.decode(Netty4SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.java:36)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
jvm 1    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
jvm 1    |      ... 20 common frames omitted
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510659/java-io-streamcorruptedexception-invalid-internal-transport-message-format)

Comment: Seems to be some configuration issue with ElasticSearch. It's complaining about HTTP being used for ElasticSearch. Maybe HTTPS was used instead of HTTP? Or the ports are wrong?

Comment: Hello, for the link it's for linux i don't think it's the same thing @sidgate

Comment: In my navigator i did http://localhost:9000 and the result is like there is no internet and it shows like localhost doesn't authirise connection. @kichik

Answer (score 1):

In {Sonar_Install_Directory}/conf/sonar.properties Please change the # Elasticsearch port. Default is 9001. Use 0 to get a free port.

## As a security precaution, should be blocked by a firewall and not exposed to the Internet.

sonar.search.port=<>

Answer (score -1):

I'd try changing the port, it may is in use:

```
sonar.properties: sonar.search.port=9002
```

Comment: Hello, i tried changing the port inside sonar in the path: sonarqube-7.4\conf but same thing